# Flutter firestore access permissions denied after enforcing app check

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

The app was working fine and had access to the firestore. Then after I enabled Appcheck right after the app started to throw this exception.

> FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

My Firebase setup is as follows

[image]

My code to enable appchek in Flutter main.dart

```
_initializeFirebase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    // Default provider for Android is the Play Integrity provider. You can use the "AndroidProvider" enum to choose
    // your preferred provider. Choose from:
    // 1. Debug provider
    // 2. Safety Net provider
    // 3. Play Integrity provider
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    // Default provider for iOS/macOS is the Device Check provider. You can use the "AppleProvider" enum to choose
    // your preferred provider. Choose from:
    // 1. Debug provider
    // 2. Device Check provider
    // 3. App Attest provider
    // 4. App Attest provider with fallback to Device Check provider (App Attest provider is only available on iOS 14.0+, macOS 14.0+)
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );
}
```

Firebase rules

```
service cloud.firestore {    
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /players/{userId} {    
      allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.name == userId;    
      allow delete: if false;
      allow read,create: if request.auth != null;    
    }    
  }    
}
```

Comment: Does Appcheck complain from invalid requests?? Could be related to an issue I am encountering (link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77116288/why-is-appcheck-randomly-generating-invalid-requests-from-published-android-but/77169839#77169839)... Let us know if you find a fix...

Answer (score 1):

Check firebase security
In the Firebase Console

- Firestore > Rules
- Make sure that the allow all

Comment: rules_version = '2';
2
service cloud.firestore {
3
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
4
    match /players/{userId} {
5
      allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.name == userId;
6
      allow delete: if false;
7
      allow read,create: if request.auth != null;
8
    }
9
  }
10
}

This is my rule. I want it to be like this. Otherwise, unauthenticated users will manipulate the db. Yes, I have firebase authentication

Comment: updated the question with my rules