# Firebase appCheck token renewal issue on Flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I have a Flutter web app and added AppCheck to it which seems to work  fine according to the firebase and captcha console (see images below).  I'm using reCAPTCHA v3 with a Token TTL of 1 day .

[image]

[image]

However, some of my users run into "permission denied" errors.

- our Flutter web app is used by multiple users in the same room
- the issue occurs on chromebooks, for some users it works, for some it doesn't; Refreshing doesn't help.

I can't reproduce it yet but it is quite likely (TBC) that they keep our web app open on their Chromebook, and run into this issue when they try our app again the day after.

In my Flutter code, at startup, I currently call

```
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider(appCheckKey)
  );
```

Should I also call the following methods?

```
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.setTokenAutoRefreshEnabled(true);
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken(true);
```

The issue looks very similar to what is reported here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6708 in the JS firebase SDK.  Apparently it is (partly) fixed in version v9.20.0

I have two questions here:

- do the JS firebase SDK and the flutter firebase SDK share some code (and hence is it likely that the Flutter SDK has/had the same appcheck token renewal issues?)
- is there a relation between the JS version numbers (9.20.0) and the version numbers of the flutter firebase plugins?

Since I can't reproduce this locally I'll go on-site next week.
I would like to get as much information out of my on-site visit so suggestions on how to tackle/analyze this issue would be appreciated:

My plan of attack is currently:

- I'll first have a look at the console log (in Chrome developer tools)
- I'll unenforce appcheck for a while to confirm that it is indeed an AppCheck issue
- is removing the IndexedDB "firebase-app-check-database" a useful test? Should I also remove IndexedDB "firebase-heartbeat-store" ?
- should running our app in incognito mode help? would it request a new token?
- can I enable firebase/appcheck logging somehow to get more details (I can create a custom build for testing if needed) ?

Additional suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I am following this stream... seems related to an issue I am encountering (link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77116288/why-is-appcheck-randomly-generating-invalid-requests-from-published-android-but)... Let us know if you find a fix...

Comment: hey OP and @Canada2000 , can you give closure on this question if you have any. thanks.

Comment: I noticed that my user got a low captcha score (0.3 or 0.1) at startup, not after keeping our app open. It was device dependent (worked fine on some devices) and network dependent (it worked fine when I used my phone as hotspot).  Not sure why they get a low captcha score.  Their IP address was not blacklisted afaics